# send post request to login from client website to service provider web

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp

client website(asp.net) has icons on which onclick event is triggered.
provider website(java)
onClick,

```
function goTourl(){
window.open(url)
}
```

url is something like this: `https://example.org/j_spring_security_check?name=testing&pass=testing'`

issue is, in spring 3 login submission doesn't allow get requests(i think)..

used following javascript to post but CSRF token issues comes up.

```
function openWindowWithPost(url,name,keys,values)
{
var newWindow = window.open(url, name); 
if (!newWindow) return false;
var html = "";
html += "<html><head></head><body><form id='formid' method='post' action='" + url + "'>";
if (keys && values && (keys.length == values.length))
for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++)
html += "<input type='hidden' name='" + keys[i] + "' value='" + values[i] + "'/>";
html += "</form><script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById(\"formid\").submit()</script></body></html>";
newWindow.document.write(html);
return newWindow;
}
```

Comment: You can not log in with a GET request since the username and password is available in plain sight! It is like putting your username and password on a postit note on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your should not be setting the url in the new window in the open.

```
var newWindow = window.open(url, name);
```

should be

```
var newWindow = window.open('', name);
```

You could avoid the whole pop up using a form on the page with the action and target set

```
<form action="https://example.org/j_spring_security_check" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
</form>
```

Comment: onClick event, client need to open a new window with provider site and auto login using the parameters comes from client site

Comment: ok..so I need to submit the form on onclick event..let me try this

Comment: thanks! it works. Is there a way to open in pop up window instead of new window?